# using commands in optional parameters

Tags: floats, optional-arguments

If I define a new command like

```
\newcommand{\command}{htb}
```

why can't I use this command to set for example the float options of an `figure` enviroment?

```
\begin{figure}[\command]
  \centering
  \[
    f(x) = x^2
  \]
  \caption{Some equation}
\end{figure}
```

this won't compile but this

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \[
    f(x) = x^2
  \]
  \caption{Some equation}
\end{figure}
```

will.

Could someone explain this and maybe how one can set a common setting for all `figure`s

Comment: If you want to change the positioning of every `figure` environment, you might redefine `\fps@figure`. The optional argument of float environments is not expanded to check which letters occur in it, you'd have to expand it beforehand, which would be a lot of `\expandafter`s. You could use `\newcommand*\myfigure[1]{\begin{figure}[{#1}]}` and then use `\expandafter\myfigure\expandafter{\command}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is primarily based on how LaTeX processes the optional argument to a float. In essence, it captures the optional argument in a different macro (`\@fps`, specifically), then attempts to expand that macro by looking at it's `\meaning`. Then it sequentially processes the characters of the meaning. However, the capturing process uses `\def`, similar to the following setup:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\abc{abc}
\def\ghi{\abc}
\meaning\ghi
```

which returns

[image]

In the above output, `macro:->` is considered "the prefix", while the exact meaning is `\abc`. With this analogy, your `\command` will result in LaTeX processing `\`, `c`, `o`, `m`, `m`, `a`, `n`, `d` sequentially and not find any match with the existing set of approved float specifications.

Simple solutions would be to define the default using the kernel functions:

```
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htb}
\makeatother
```

Or you could use the [`float` package](//ctan.org/pkg/float):

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{htb}
```

Or, if you're extremely dedicated, you could try a patch on `\@xfloat`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@xfloat}% <cmd>
  {\def \@fps}% <search>
  {\edef\@fps}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

The above replaces the traditional `\def` with an `e`xpanded version. It allows you to use your setup

```
\begin{figure}[\command]
  % <your figure>
\end{figure}
```